# The submit button is not functioning in html, even though i gave onclick element

Tags: javascript, html, django

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script> 
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn1").click(function(){
                $(".btn1").show();
                $(".btn1").attr("disabled",true);
        });
    });
    function getanswer()
    {
        document.getElementById("useranswer").innerHTML = "";
        var e = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for(i = 0; i<= e.length ; i++)
        {
            if(e[i].type == 'radio')
            {
                if(e[i].checked)
                {
                    document.getElementById("useranswer").innerHTML += "Q" + e[i].name + "Answer you selected is :" + e[i].value+ "<br/>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

This is script code for the below html line

```
  <main class="questions">
        {% for Result in QUIZFORM %}
            <table>
                <br>
                <tr>
                    <td>{{Result.id}} ) {{Result.questions}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" id="choice1" name="{{Result.id}}" class="ans" value="{{Result.choice1}}">{{Result.choice1}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" id="choice1"   name="{{Result.id}}" class="ans" value="{{Result.choice2}}">{{Result.choice2}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" id="choice1"   name="{{Result.id}}" class="ans" value="{{Result.choice3}}">{{Result.choice3}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="radio" id="choice1"   name="{{Result.id}}" class="ans" value="{{Result.choice4}}">{{Result.choice4}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><label id="correctanswer" class="ans" value="{{Result.correctanswer}}" style="display: none; color:green;">{{Result.correctanswer}}</label></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            {% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="submitanswer" id="btn1" onclick = " getanswer();" >
```

And the **submit** button is not working if i click on that.

Can anyone help me out with this, what is problem  going on. Whenever the **submitanswer** is
clicked it is not functioning. What i expected is : it should jump to getanswer function and display the following propertys. Please help me with this. And i am working with Django framework. I am using this function to validate the user answers. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to removed the first space before `getanwser();` in your html? -> onclick = "getanswer();"

Try also the `<button></button>` tag

Comment: The issue is most likely in the `getanswer` function rather than the onclick event. Try adding quotations to `useranswer` in the HTML DOM like so: `document.getElementById("useranswer").innerHTML`

Comment: I came here to say the exact same thing as Vassilis. I bet it is that.

Comment: @juanmajmjr I tried that `<button></button>` didn't work, even the whitespace.

Comment: @Vassilis Yeah! I tried now, didn't make any difference in the output. I tried to insert " " in both the cases for `useranswer`.

Comment: @Vassilis `function getanswer()
    {
        document.getElementById("useranswer").innerHTML = "";
        
                {
                    document.getElementById("useranswer").innerHTML += "Q" + e[i].name + "Answer you selected is :" + e[i].value+ "<br/>";
                }
            }
        }
    }`  see the corrected code. **The other in between code remains  the same**

Comment: Maybe try see the error it's throwing in the console, using Chrome dev tools or whatever browser you are using... So we can narrow down the problem.

Comment: Can you share the full html & javascript code?

Comment: @AjayLingayat yeah see above i have edited and included my html and JS code, check in the main section. In the top field.

Comment: @AjayLingayat Have you checked this out?

Comment: I copied your code and it was running fine and the function `getanswer()` was getting called. try this : `<button type="submit" id="btn1" onclick="getanswer()"> submitanswer </button>`.

Comment: @Aravinda KS Actually I think the problem is var e is trying to get input from all input tags but botton is not giving any input than click hence may be that's not working.

Comment: @AjayLingayat It is throwing an error  ```{ 2(index):40 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at getanswer ((index):40)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):204)} ``` in the console.

Comment: Okay I get it why it may not be working. @AravindaKS have you declared any html element which has `id` attribute as `useranswer`? becuase the error you got clearly states that it is unable to find an element with `id="useranswer"`